# docker postgresql не запускается при монтировании папки

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

создаю контейнер с postgresql

```
sudo docker run --name ndflka_db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -p 5433:5432 -v /media/alex/Data/docker_container/ndflka_db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:11
```

При проверке запущен ли контейнер - он выключен.
Тут возможна проблема с доступом или еще что-то, но опыта мало и я не понимаю чего не хватает. С windows пробовал сработало, с linux уперлось и не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в логах контейнера нашел такое, как это исправить, я плохо понимаю в правах, как бы общий смысл понимаю но кому сейчас какие права дать без понятия

> chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation
> not permitted The files belonging to this database system will be
> owned by user "postgres". This user must also own the server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8". The
> default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8". The
> default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> Data page checksums are disabled.
>
> initdb: could not change permissions of directory
> "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted fixing permissions
> on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... chmod: changing
> permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted The
> files belonging to this database system will be owned by user
> "postgres". This user must also own the server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8". The
> default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8". The
> default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> Data page checksums are disabled.
>
> initdb: could not change permissions of directory
> "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted fixing permissions
> on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ...

Comment: а вы логи этого контейнера проверяли? `docker logs ndflka_db `

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `-e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` перед -v

Comment: Попробуйте на уровень ниже монтировать папку: `/var/lib/postgresql`